# How do i include and declare an image source variable

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to switch some "key numbers" provided by a json string, to some specific words, it's working by now, but i also need to print a different image for each case. How do i include a variable that prints an image source (not provided by the json string) or is there any other way to print (echo) a different image for each "key number"?

**I have no access to the json file, it doesn't have images sources, i have to write the image src "by hand" in each case. And i don't know the syntax to do that.**

```
<?PHP
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$json = file_get_contents('http://example.20.22.8/cartelera/M');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
$img =
    $sesiondia = date('w', strtotime($date));
//var_dump($obj->cartelera);
for($i=0; $i<count($obj['cartelera']); $i++) {
    switch($obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave'])
    {   
    case ($obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave'] == '182') :
        $obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave'] = 'Contraseña verde';
        break;

    case ($obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave'] == '183') :
        $obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave'] = 'La tierra vista por Alban';
        break;
    }

    if ($obj['cartelera'][$i]['barra_clave'] == '13')
    {
        if ($date == substr($obj['cartelera'][$i]['fecha'], 0, 10 ))
        {
            if($obj['cartelera'][$i]['hora_inicio'] < '12:00')
            {
                if ($dias[$sesiondia] == 'Domingo' && $obj['cartelera'][$i]['hora_inicio'] == '07:00')
                {
                    echo "<li><span class='hora'>".$obj['cartelera'][$i]['hora_inicio']."</span>".$obj['cartelera'][$i]['titulo']."</li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li><span class='hora'>".$obj['cartelera'][$i]['hora_inicio']."</span>".$obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave']."</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        else {}
    }
    else {}
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

By now my code looks like this, but i need to add an image for each line
[image]

Comment: Where do the image URLs come from if not from the JSON?

Comment: BTW, I think you'll find working with arrays easier if you use `foreach` instead of `for`. You won't have to keep repeating `$obj['cartelera'][$i]`.

Comment: `case ($obj['cartelera'][$i]['serie_clave'] == '182')` should be `case '182':`. You already specified the variable to compare with in the `switch()` statement, the `case` should only contain the value.

Comment: That's the thing, i have no access to the json file, it doesn't have images sources, i have to write the image src "by hand" in each case. And i don't know the syntax to do that. Thank you so much for your advise.

Comment: It's still not clear. Where are the image files, is there some way to determine which image to display depending on the information that's in the JSON?

Comment: What do you mean by "write the image src by hand"? Are you talking about a `data:` URL where the image data is in base64 format, instead of getting the image from a file on the server?